# Why am I expected to use parentheses notation instead of regular dot notation when defining foreign key relationships?

Tags: mysql, foreign-key

Here's basic SQL code

```sql
create table users (
  id int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  name varchar(50), 
  last_name varchar(50), 
  age tinyint
);

insert into users (name, last_name, age) 
values 
("John", "Doe", 30),
("Jane", "Doe", 35);

create table departments (
  user_id int,
  department varchar(50),
  foreign key (user_id) references users(id)
);

insert into departments
values  
(1, "IT"), 
(2, "HR");
```

I didn't question it before, but at this point it just looks too weird to me so I decided to post a question on this. Why am I expected to use parentheses notation instead of regular dot notation when defining foreign key relationships? Why isn't

```sql
foreign key user_id references users.id
```

valid syntax? I don't see how it may cause any ambiguity or anything

I'm not sure "why" questions are on topic here, but I hope they are

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the source and target of a foreign key is a tuple not a column.  Eg the target table may have a compound key, and the foreign key would look like:

```
foreign key (TenantId, Id) references users(TenantId, Id)
```

Comment: One more variant: `foreign key ( txt_column(10) ) references users ( txt_column(10) )`. Dot-style syntax should be `references users.txt_column(10)`? Obvious nonsense..